# What is the best way to create parameter of the component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create simple, popular type of component: a component to create/update some business object. Of course in this type of component we have two modes: `add` and `edit`.

The obvious solution is a property and text value.

```
<Foo mode="add"/>
<Foo mode="edit"/>
```

I'm thinking if there's any neat way to expose mode so that developer can chose from some specified values?

I tried to find some example but it seems that this "text parameter" approach is somehow popular. For example in [material ui](https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/) mode/type of button is done in the same way (`variant` property):

```
<Button variant="fab" color="secondary" aria-label="Edit" className={classes.button}>
    <Icon>edit_icon</Icon>
</Button>
<Button variant="extendedFab" aria-label="Delete" className={classes.button}>
    <NavigationIcon className={classes.extendedIcon} />
    Extended
</Button>
```

Is there any better way? Is it possible to create some convenient enum or something like that?

**UPDATE**

The question is not about how to implement the mode of component, but how to more neatly specify the mode. For example instead of

```
<Foo mode="add"/>
<Foo mode="edit"/>
```

I'd like to have something like this:

```
<Foo mode={FooModes.add}/>
<Foo mode={FooModes.edit}/>
```

or

```
<Foo edit/>
<Foo add/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have done sth like that :)

```
export default class myAmazingComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  generateComponent = (mode) => {
    switch(mode) {
      case 'FOO' :
        return <div>FOO Mode is activated</div>;
      case 'BAR' :
        return <div>BAR Mode is activated</div>;
      default:
        return <div>DEFAULT mode</div>
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { mode } = this.props;
    return (
      this.generateComponent(mode)
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but it seems to me that you are trying to conditionally render something.

What I usually do about this, is contain both types of content in their own class property / method like so:

```
optionA = () => {
  // return the component in style A here
}
optionB = () => {
  // return the component in style B here
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      {this.props.mode === 'add' ? optionA() : optionB()
    </div>
  )
}
```

This way you can render either option depending on passed props. (if 'add' it will render the JSX returned by optionA(), else it will render optionB()'s output)

Also this is a very simple example of how I like to structure my components, would love feedback here!

React's docs are really good btw, you can find more about conditional rendering here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Hope this helped